# 1Up Industries's Bins-like for Unity Launcher?

Tags: unity

I'm curious if there is an application for Ubuntu that allows for the type of functionality given by Bins ([link here](http://www.1upindustries.com/bins/)). Would like to group IDEs and web browsers in a similar fashion.

edit: I'm not looking for the App Drawer of Android. If anything, more like the folders on the home screen for Android just contained within the Unity Launcher. So I could click or mouseover the "folder," and I'd see a small group of icons (ie hover over development "folder" and see WebStorm, Sublime Text, Eclipse, etc.)

I'm thinking that Drawers answer may be in line with what I'm looking for (not concerned with text vs icons). Will test when I get home and mark as answer if so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there something similar to the Android AppDrawer/App Launcher?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43093/is-there-something-similar-to-the-android-appdrawer-app-launcher)

Comment: Does not seems like a duplicate of that question. It seems like he is asking for a different kind of taskbar grouping. Robert, you may want to update your question to have more details about what you looking for. Maybe a sample use case (I would love task manager like that but can't think of one).

Comment: The question is different however the answer is pretty much what the OP is looking for.

Comment: I see. You're right that Drawers seems to be the suggested application in both cases, though I was kind of hoping something a bit closer to Bins (it requires very little movement of the mouse from my experience). That said, upvoted and I'll go with Drawers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Drawers" might be what you are looking for:
http://www.noobslab.com/2013/03/unity-launcher-drawers-for-ubuntu.html

Comment: it isn't as clean or easy to use as Bins, but appears to be the closest thing available.